# Filter to show/hide bootstrap table rows with empty column cell value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mean-stack

I am developing a web application using MEAN stack which contains 1 table(bootstrap) with 2 column and multiple rows. `Column 1` will have data for every single row but not necessary for `Column 2`. [image]

I want to put a filter like `Mapped`(show rows with values in both column) ,`UnMapped`(show rows with value in only first column) and `All`(show all rows). The filters will be given as option in drop down as:

```
 <select class="selectpicker form-control">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Mapped">Mapped</option>
    <option value="UnMapped">Un-Mapped</option>
 </select>
```

I tried different solutions to filter table but unable to figure out solution for above scenario. Please Help.

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjfPa/261/):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
 <select class="selectpicker form-control" ng-model="test">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Mapped">Mapped</option>
    <option value="UnMapped">Un-Mapped</option>
 </select>  
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:emptyOrNull">
    {{ x.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'All';
    $scope.names = [{
            name: 'Mapped',
            address: 'SomeData'
        },
        {
            name: 'UnMapped'
        },
    ];

    $scope.emptyOrNull = function (item) {
        if ($scope.test == "All")
            return true;
        if ($scope.test == "Mapped")
            return item.name && item.address
        if ($scope.test == "UnMapped")
            return !(item.address) ;
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```