# Preventing filter while editing table content in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425447/filter-to-show-hide-bootstrap-table-rows-with-empty-column-cell-value)

I am able to successfully apply filter for my table. Now I want to change the way this filter is working. Here is the situation:

1. I am applying `Mapped` filter. It filtered out all mapped variables for me. Now I will change the value of one of the filtered variables, as soon as I delete the complete value, the variable is moved to `Unmapped` list and User is not able to change the variable. User now need to change the filter to either `All` or `UnMapped` filter to edit that variable.
2. Same in the case of `Unmapped` filter. Select `Unmapped` filter, as soon as I try entering value, the variable disappears and moved to 'Mapped' list.

What I need to do is to apply filter only when I select filter from drop down using ng-change and when I try to edit some variable the filter should not work.

Here is the code:

For Filter :

```
 $scope.filterOpt = 'All';
    $scope.emptyOrNull = function (variable) {
        if ($scope.filterOpt == "All")
            return true;
        if ($scope.filterOpt == "Mapped")
            return variable.Name && variable.Variable
        if ($scope.filterOpt == "UnMapped")
            return !(variable.Variable) ;
    }
```

HTML :

```
 <select class="selectpicker form-control" ng-model="filterOpt" ng-change="emptyOrNull()">
   <option value="All">All</option>
   <option value="Mapped">Mapped</option>
   <option value="UnMapped">Un-Mapped</option>
 </select>
```

and Table:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="var in Mappings | filter: searchVariable | filter : emptyOrNull">
   <td>{{var.Name}}</td>
    <td>
     <div><input-dropdown name="fqn" ng-model="var.Variable" list="variables" ng-disabled="var.IsTrue"></input-dropdown></div> 
    </td>
   </tr>
```

UI :

[image]

In above picture when I select Mapped from filter and try to change/delete `Value1` it should not disappear.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I don't understand why do you want `| filter : emptyOrNull`, when you want to update UI only if you change the dropdown value.

Why don't you only update array(`$scope.Mappings`). In this array you can only push values you want to display.

Remove filter and update your dropdown `ng-change` function like this

Here `origArray` is your original array, I am just changing scope variables

```
$scope.emptyOrNull = function (variable) {
    $scope.Mappings = [];
    if ($scope.filterOpt == "All") {
        $scope.Mappings = angular.copy(origArray);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < origArray.length; i++) {
           if ($scope.filterOpt == "Mapped") {
               if (origArray[i].Name && origArray[i].Variable) {
                   $scope.Mappings.push(origArray[i]);
               }
           }

           if ($scope.filterOpt == "UnMapped") {
               if (!origArray[i].Variable) {
                   $scope.Mappings.push(origArray[i]);
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Don't use filter for this kind of requirements, it reduces performance.

Comment: Ahh that's my mistake....and this is what I am looking for. and about the performance, i am struggling to come over that. i am having thousands of variable which take a lot of time to render.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add a conditional filter. That means apply filter only when you want it to be and don't apply when you don't want.

you can check when input is focused with something like and toggle a variable to disable or enable filter

`<input-dropdown name="fqn" ng-model="var.Variable" ng-focus="disable=true" list="variables" ng-disabled="var.IsTrue"></input-dropdown>`

And to do conditional filtering use

`<tr ng-repeat="var in Mappings | filter : (disable ? '' : emptyOrNull)">`

And then you can update the `disable` to `true` on changing `mapped/unmapped` dropdown.

Hope this helps